# Why does my nextjs 13 project returns 502 - bad gateway for rsc payload fetching?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, next.js

I'm uploading a nextjs 13 project to a VPS, but the links at the project home wasn't working as expected. So I opened the network tab and have seen it:

[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eamn.png)

Each url of these requests has the structure "/product/{id}?_rsc={hex}", and "/product/{id}" is the url that my links are pointing to, so I think it is correlated (probably prefetching of pages).

These requests stay pending until it resolve to 502 - bad gateway and I don't know the reason for it.

My environment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Node 16.14.0, Nginx 1.18.0, NextJS 13.4.7

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).